# Apache superset - Error adding new metric with unknow reason

Tags: metrics, apache-superset

I need some help. Just start using Superset and I get this error when adding new metric.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMR7t.png)
The new metric I want to add is quite simple

```
COUNT(user_pseudo_id)
```

The error message is vague.
How can I fix this?

I have tried to change the metric name, even change the query so it's exactly like the sample one that I automatically get (COUNT(*))